# Why is the gamma term missing in the first case of single transistor example?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, physics, vlsi

[image]

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qU6jRqvrlA&t=478s) is the video.

How is the gamma term present in one case and absent in another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient gamma, arises when there is body effect i.e when source and body are not at same potential.

Here, in the first case, soure and body potentials of N0 are same. So, there is no gamma factor. While in the second case, N1 has different body and source voltages.
To get clarity, u can go through the equation of Threshold voltage and Body effect.